# Get child entities returns null instead of arrayCollection object

Tags: symfony, doctrine

I have two entities with a oneToMany relationship:

Post entity:

```
...
oneToMany:
  images:
    mappedBy: post
    targetEntity: Shop\Bundle\ManagementBundle\Entity\Image
```

Image entity:

```
...
    manyToOne:
        post:
            targetEntity: Shop\Bundle\ManagementBundle\Entity\Post
            inversedBy: images
            joinColumn:
                onDelete: cascade
```

With `$entity` instance of `Post`, when I was doing `$entity->getImages()`, I was receiving something like:

```
     object(Doctrine\ORM\PersistentCollection)[65]
      private 'snapshot' => 
        array (size=0)
          empty
      private 'owner' => 
        object(Acme\Bundle\ImageUpBundle\Entity\Post)[54]
          private 'id' => int 41
          private 'title' => string 'kbd' (length=3)
          private 'images' => 
            &object(Doctrine\ORM\PersistentCollection)[65]
      private 'association' => 
        array (size=15)
          'fieldName' => string 'images' (length=6)
          'targetEntity' => string 'Shop\Bundle\ManagementBundle\Entity\Image' (length=38)
          'mappedBy' => string 'post' (length=4)
          'type' => int 4
          'inversedBy' => null
          'isOwningSide' => boolean false
          'sourceEntity' => string 'Shop\Bundle\ManagementBundle\Entity\Post' (length=37)
          'fetch' => int 2
          'cascade' => 
            array (size=0)
              empty
          'isCascadeRemove' => boolean false
          'isCascadePersist' => boolean false
          'isCascadeRefresh' => boolean false
          'isCascadeMerge' => boolean false
          'isCascadeDetach' => boolean false
          'orphanRemoval' => boolean false
      private 'em' =>
....
```

But now i unfortunately get `null`.

I really did all my best to figure out what might cause such issue. Your help is much appreciated.

**Edit:**

given an in integer $id, I fetch a Post entity using:

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
$entity = $em->getRepository('ShopManagementBundle:Post')->find($id);
```

I successfully get all the attributes of Post entity except from `images`.

Comment: Does the entity you work with have any images associated?

Comment: @xabbuh, do you mean in database? if so, yes. images persist with correct foreigh key.

Comment: Can you then please show soe more code? How do you fetch the entity for example?

Comment: @xabbuh, thank you for your time, I have edited the OP adding an answer to your last question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well here are the things that solved my issue:

1- I gathered all One To Many associations under one `oneToMany` parameter in config file. In other words, instead of having:

```
oneToMany: 
  images:
     targetEntity....
     ....
oneToMany:
   messages:
      targerEntity...
      ....
```

I would have:

```
oneToMany:
   images:
      targerEntity...
      ....
   messages:
      targerEntity...
      ....
```

2. I generated entities again using `app/console doc:gen:entities` making the only one constructor constructs the two `ArrayCollection`s.

> ```
> /**
>      * Constructor
>      */
>     public function __construct()
>     {
>         $this->messages = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
>         $this->images = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
>     }
> ```

Now when I call `$em->getRepository('ShopManagementBundle:Post)->find($id)` I have the child entities (`Images`) attached to my parent entity (`Post`) when concrete records exist in database, and not Null. When I insantiate a new entity using `new Post()`, I have empty ArrayCollection and not Null.

I know this answer is lacking of programming logic and seems arbitrary effort, but I write it in the sake of sharing in the case someone encounters suddenly this problem (As I did). I hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

```
$entity = $em->getRepository('ShopManagementBundle:Post')->find($id);
```

By Default, you will get only the proxy object of the child entities, this  lazy way of fetching the associated entities is called Lazy loading, which will fetch values from images entity only a call to its getter method is invoked such as

```
$entity->getImage();
```

To load all the associated entities at one shot, you should instruct doctrine to do eager loading. This can be done using DQL, unfortunately its not possible to instruct using find method

```
$query = $em->createQuery("SELECT p FROM Shop\Bundle\ManagementBundle\Entity\Post p");
$query->setFetchMode("Shop\Bundle\ManagementBundle\Entity\Post", "images", \Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\ClassMetadata::FETCH_EAGER);
$query->execute();
```

Comment: I get your point Sir, and thank you for informing me this. However I cannot understand why the lazy loading suddenly stopped working. Even `$entity->getImages()` gives null right now. In the whole project, I was sending `$entity` to twig template and looping over `entity.images`, now this is broken. I will be implementing eager loading but honnestly...hm headached why the original behavious stopped working

Comment: Do you have enough data in images table to point to a row in post table

Comment: Thank you Sir for you feedback again. I think I found the solution in the time between now and my last comment. I will be here to share it once I am done.Thanks again

Comment: I have posted the solution, I hope it helps. Thank you again for the time you have given to my issue. BR

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your column name, member name and method naming all syntactically align. For example 'searchCampaignType':

ORM Column: searchCampaignTypeId
Member: $searchCampaignType
Getter: getSearchCampaignTypes
Setter: setSearchCampaignTypes

Other steps to take:

- Regenerate your Doctrine Proxies
- If you are using memcached then ensure you restart it or
  rebuild the data

The question was oneToMany. The example below is ManyToMany but the principle is the same.

```
 /**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="CampaignType")
 * @ORM\JoinTable(name="Roles__SearchCampaignTypes",
 *      joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="roleId", referencedColumnName="id")},
 *      inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="searchCampaignTypeId", referencedColumnName="id")}
 *      )
 **/
private $searchCampaignTypes;

/**
 * @return ArrayCollection
 */
public function getSearchCampaignTypes()
{
    return $this->searchCampaignTypes;
}

/**
 * @param $searchCampaignTypes
 */
public function setSearchCampaignTypes($searchCampaignTypes)
{
    $this->searchCampaignTypes = $searchCampaignTypes;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the hint of @satdev86 due to proxies, I could solve the problem in my case by only regenerating the proxies with `orm:generate-proxies`.