# why null instead of empty arrayCollection?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine, symfony1

I have two entities with a oneToMany relationship:

Post entity:

```
...
oneToMany:
  images:
    mappedBy: post
    targetEntity: Shop\Bundle\ManagementBundle\Entity\Image
```

Image entity:

```
...
    manyToOne:
        post:
            targetEntity: Shop\Bundle\ManagementBundle\Entity\Post
            inversedBy: images
            joinColumn:
                onDelete: cascade
```

when I do `$entity->getImages()`, I receive `null`. Even if in database there are many images linked to a post.

I really did all my best to figure out what might cause such issue. Your usual help is much appreciated.

**PS:**
Given an integer `$id`, I fetch a Post entity in controller using:

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
$entity = $em->getRepository('ShopManagementBundle:Post')->find($id);
```

I successfully get all the attributes of Post entity except from images. When I do `$entity= new Post`, `getImages` gives an empty arrayCollection!!.

**solution**:

[Get child entities returns null instead of arrayCollection object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34725409/get-child-entities-returns-null-instead-of-arraycollection-object)

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing about join columns in configuration. Try to add this info.

```
manyToOne:
    post:
        targetEntity: Shop\Bundle\ManagementBundle\Entity\Post
        inversedBy: images
        ...
        joinColumns:
            post_id:
                referencedColumnName: id
        ...
        cascade: { }
```

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. I already have the joinColumn config. About the cascade, I already tried it to no avail. :(

Comment: Sir, thank you for your time, I posted the solution I hope it helps